# Three.js wrong Normals and Faces after using MeshPhongMaterial displacementMap

Tags: three.js, terrain, vertices, heightmap

I´m using the displacementMap attribute in the MeshPhongMaterial with a loaded greyscaled texture. The extrusion/displacement works fine but the normals and faces of the effected mesh.geometry does not get updated.

I used

```
geometry.computeFaceNormals()
```

and

```
geometry.computeVertexNormals().
```

I want to make a walkable character on the terrain by ray-casting down and receiving the height (y) value of the intersected face/vertice for the chaarcters offset manipulation.

Enclosed an img of the current displaced geometry with the VertexNormalsHelper(red lines) and the FaceNormalsHelper(green lines ) applied.

Does someone know how to update them correctly?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The displacement map will only be applied in the vertex shader, meaning the fundamental geometry isn't actually altered, and the fundamental geometry is what the helper is showing.

You would have to iterate and change the actual vertices in the geometry buffer itself to alter them.

The same of course applies for the raycaster intersection test which will use the fundamental vertices/faces.

> I want to make a walkable character on the terrain by ray-casting down and receiving the height (y)

**A possible workaround** to avoid altering the geometry is to first get the UV position of your character on the plane, then map that to a 2D position on the displacement map. Finally pick the value at that point, scale and use that for height relative to the mesh.

This may even be more efficient than using raycasting, but you might have to do interpolation for positions that isn't on a vertex.